# How to know which DB I've associated with Firebase?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've set-up up my AS to use Firebase. How to know/change the Firebase app/Database I'm using in my app from Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already setted your project, you must have downloaded a `google-services.json` and put it in the *app* folder. So, in that json, you can find your database url.

Comment: Thank you, I've setted it up using Android Studio and missed that file from the Project's view.